# Entity Framework Generic repository including properties through parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have an implementation of a Generic Repository in Entity Framework which I am trying to improve to use the .Include(..) function provided by EF instead of including the navigation properties by string, in order to be able to safely rename properties.

Below is my current code:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query);
        }
        else
        {
            return query;
        }
    }
```

I currently use this in the following way:

```
repository.GetAll(
    u => u.Name = "John",
    u => u.OrderBy(x => x.Name),
    "Address.State",
);
```

My question is: how can I change the method in order to be able to call it in the following way (or similar):

```
repository.GetAll(
    u => u.Name = "John",
    u => u.OrderBy(x => x.Name),
    u => u.Include(x => x.Address).ThenInclude(x => x.State),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected internal IQueryable<TEntity> Filter(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var query = RetrieveQuery();

    if (predicate != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
    }

    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        query = _queryableUnitOfWork.ApplyIncludesOnQuery(query, includeProperties);
    }

    return (query);
}
```

And this method called there

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyIncludesOnQuery<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties) where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    // Return Applied Includes query
    return (includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include)));
}
```

Filter Method Call

```
 public IEnumerable<ShowStockProductDto> GetActiveShowStockProductListByProduct(int productId)
            {
                var foundedPStockroducts = Filter(
                    ent => ent.ProductId == productId && ent.IsActive,
                    ent => ent.StockProductPrices,
                    ent => ent.StockProductDepots,
                    ent => ent.StockProductSpecificationValues,
                    ent => ent.StockProductSpecificationValues.Select(spsv => spsv.SpecificationValue)
                    );

                // Map foundedPStockroducts to showStockProductList
                var showStockProductList = TypeAdapterFactory.Adapter.Adapt<IEnumerable<ShowStockProductDto>>(foundedPStockroducts).ToList();

                return (showStockProductList);
            }
```

Comment: just working on this matter some days ago in my own project

Comment: and yes, i am new on answering the question on stackoverflow, i am very welcome :/

Comment: @NaDeR-Star why do you need the 2 following lines:

    ent => ent.StockProductSpecificationValues,

    ent => ent.StockProductSpecificationValues.Select(spsv => spsv.SpecificationValue)

Comment: that includes SpecificationValue navigation property of StockProductSpecificationValues Clollection

Comment: ent => ent.StockProductSpecificationValues
is a collection and
ent => ent.StockProductSpecificationValues.Select(spsv => spsv.SpecificationValue)
is a navigation there

Comment: And isn't the first line redundant? I mean, only with the second line with the select aren't you already including the StockProductSpecificationValues and SpecificationValue inside them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185896/discussion-between-nader-star-and-gmesorio).

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you to keep two methods, one accepting string params and one expression params. Some of the clients of your repository can work better with the string signature and some of them can work better with expression signature which brings IntelliSense for them.

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll(params string[] including)
{
    var query = dbSet.AsQueryable();
    if (including != null)
        including.ToList().ForEach(include =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(include))
                query = query.Include(include);
        });
    return query;
}

public IQueryable<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] including)
{
    var query = dbSet.AsQueryable();
    if (including != null)
        including.ToList().ForEach(include =>
        {
            if (include != null)
                query = query.Include(include);
        });
    return query;
}
```

Make sure you have added `using System.Data.Entity;`.

You can implement the logic for filter and sort the same way. For the string params signature for filter and sort, you can use `System.Linq.Dynamic` package.

**Example:**

```
var result1 = schoolRepository.GetAll("Students", "Teachers");
var result2 = schoolRepository.GetAll(x=>x.Students, x=>x.Teachers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties` instead of string parameter

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query);
        }
        else
        {
            return query;
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you include child properties from lists. for example: includeProperties: u => u.Addresses.Select(a => a.State.Country) should pull me the address list for the users, each of them populated with the State, but instead it is throwing an error