# Use generic include function in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, generic-programming

I have this generic include in ASP.NET Core:

```
 public IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
 {
     IQueryable<T> query = _uow.Set<T>();

     return includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
 }
```

I have two tables:

```
public class Brand
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string BFaName { get; set; }
    public string BEnName { get; set; }
    public int CatId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductBrand> ProductBrands { get; set; }
}

public class ProductBrand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

I need to find `BrandId` from `Brand` table by `ProductID` in `Product`.

How can I use this generic include to find the `BrandID`? What should I pass to this generic include?

Comment: Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965044/entity-framework-generic-repository-including-properties-through-parameter/53965100#53965100)

Answer (score -1):

I assume that the include function works as expected. Then

```cs
int brandId = 12;

var product = AllIncluding(a => a.Product).Single(a => a.Id == brandId);

// your result here
var brand = product.Brand;
```

or 'oneliner'

```cs
var brand = AllIncluding(a => a.Product)
     .Single(a => a.Id == 12).Brand;
```

> Note that `Single` is not null safe!

If you would need more includings:

```
var brand = AllIncluding(a => a.Product, a => a.Brand, ...)
...
```

Since you are using the keyword `params`, you are able to pass multiple include statements at once.

Comment: my question about pass parametr in that generic not use the include