# Navigation Properties not returning when included using a loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a repository pattern implementation and i am trying to include Navigation Properties "User" and "Transactions" using a loop. it doesn't work. 
is set to

```
Dbset = _context.Set<TEntity>()



 public async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes = null)
    {
        //if (includes != null)
        //{

        //    foreach (var item in includes)
        //    {
        //        DbSet.Include(item);
        //    }
        //}
        //return await DbSet.ToListAsync();
        var dd = DbSet.Include(includes[0]);
        var result = await dd.ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

commented out code is what i am trying. But if i try one property it works.

the entities look like this.

```
   public class Account : BaseEntity
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountTitle { get; set; }
    public double CurrentBalance { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public AccountStatus AccountStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
public enum AccountStatus
{
    Active = 0,
    InActive = 1
}

public class Transaction : BaseEntity
{
    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public double TransactionAmount { get; set; }
}
public enum TransactionType{
    Deposit = 0,
    Widraw = 1
}

 public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `var dd = await includes.Aggregate(DbSet, (query, item) => query.Include(item)).ToListAsync()` - you need to chain all includes into one query. `Include` method returns new instance of query. So on every iteration you need to assign result query to the variable and apply next expression to that result.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<TEntity>'.

Comment: [Entity Framework Generic repository including properties through parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53965174/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
public async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes = null)
{

    var query = _context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in includes)
        {
            query.Include(item);
        }
    }

    var result =  await query.ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Its the same code i have commented above. Dbset = _context.Set<TEntity>()
didn't worked.

Comment: I didn't see any initialization for `Dbset` in your Question. Add it to your question.

Comment: yes sir my mistake. i just added.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is a mix of what Hamed said "DBSet.AsQuerable" and what Fabio said

```
   public async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes = null)
    {
        var query = DbSet.AsQueryable();
        if (includes != null)
        {
            query = includes.Aggregate(query,
              (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }
        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Useful convention - collections can not be `null` - always return empty collection or pass empty collection to the methods when there is nothing to provide. Then you can get rid of all `null` checks on collections.